# Ansible apt Task: Failed to Lock apt for Exclusive Operation

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I have written an Ansible playbook that includes running `apt-get dist-upgrade`. I made sure to have `become: true` and `become_user: root` at the top of the playbook in order to get sudo access to run the upgrade. This works fine locally on my Vagrant VMs, but when running on our production systems (Ubuntu 16.04) we get the following error:

`Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation`

Our current workaround is to SSH into the machine and then manually run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Then exit the SSH session and run the ansible playbook again and it works.

Other tasks in our playbook require sudo access and work fine. It is just the apt command that fails. We have tried rebooting the machines and replacing `become: true` and `become_user: root` with `sudo: yes` to no avail.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? I'll include the pertinent parts of our playbook below.

```
- become: true
  become_user: root
  name: Setup the mongo database servers
  hosts: sgmongo-{{ customer }}-ciadmin
  tasks:
    -
      name: Ensure OS is upgraded with all patches
      apt: upgrade=dist update_cache=yes
```

Comment: Is there any cron action or other that is running `apt` on your production system? This kind of error indicate multiple concurrent access to `apt`. Also take a look at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/search?q=%22Failed+to+lock+apt+for+exclusive+operation%22&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 4):

I do it by calling a shell script with Ansible like so:

```
- script: ./files/bash_scripts/monitor_automatic_updates_status.sh
```

The script in question that Ansible calls is here:

```
#!/bin/bash  
#Debian automatically checks for updates on first boot. This ensures that has completed before continuing.
#If it hasn't finished in 10 minutes, the script will exit ungracefully.
timeout=$(($(date +%s) + 600))

while pgrep apt > /dev/null; do

    time=$(date +%s)

    if [[ $time -ge $timeout ]];
    then
        exit 1
    fi

    sleep 1
done;
exit 0
```

It just continually checks if `apt` is running on the system or not. And, when it finally finishes running, allows Ansible to continue.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have interrupted the apt command. Try to delete the apt lock file under `/var/lib/apt` by running:

`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Comment: This is a bad suggestion. You're literally removing the lock from a running apt task which can cause conflicts. 

The reason this is happening is because Debian is trying to automatically update the first time it boots after Ansible provisions it. Either have the command try and run until it succeeds or run it at a later time in the playbook.

Comment: @TJZimmerman Can you tell me how to run the command later from Ansible?

Comment: I added a comment with my solution.

Comment: Surely this is fine if you have already run `ps -ef | grep apt` and nothing is showing up?